# Returns only one value when trying to add scraped data to the list, Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape data from websites and first portion of my code seems to work.
However, when I try to add that data to the list it returns only one value from the **scraped** data.
I thought maybe it's recognized as a string, tried separators, didn't work.
Please help!

I used Goodgle Colab

Thanks in advance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster"
page = requests.get(url)

page.content  ##content of classes, for the problem we need "sidearm-roster-player-height" class
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
height_swimmers = soup.findAll('span', class_ = 'sidearm-roster-player-height')
print(height_swimmers)

for text in height_swimmers:
  height = text.get_text()
  print(height)
height_list = []
height_list.append(height)

print(height_list)
```

Comment: So, you want to print all the values that you print with `print(height)` in a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the for loop, you only add the last value of `height` to `height_list`.

In order to print *all* scraped results in a list, use

```py
height_list = []

for text in height_swimmers:
    height = text.get_text()
    print(height)
    height_list.append(height)
```

instead of

```py
for text in height_swimmers:
    height = text.get_text()
    print(height)
height_list = []
height_list.append(height)
```

Comment: PS: if you want it to be extra concise, you could also use list comprehensions instead: `height_list = [text.get_text() for text in height_swimmers]`

Answer (score 0):

Put this line before the for:

```
height_list = []
```

and this inside of it:

```
height_list.append(height)
```

this way you append the height of each iteration to the list

so the full code should be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://athletics.baruch.cuny.edu/sports/mens-swimming-and-diving/roster"
page = requests.get(url)

page.content  ##content of classes, for the problem we need "sidearm-roster-player-height" class
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
height_swimmers = soup.findAll('span', class_ = 'sidearm-roster-player-height')
print(height_swimmers)

height_list = []
for text in height_swimmers:
  height = text.get_text()
  print(height)
  height_list.append(height)

print(height_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can't believe I couldn't see it. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, btw you should mark this question as corretly answered so users can see it

Answer (score -1):

indentation is the issue here, all the statements under for loop should have same indentation, if not then you will capture only the last value in it and that is the issue now.

for text in height_swimmers:
height = text.get_text()
print(height)
***height_list = []
height_list.append(height)***

print(height_list)